# apacheでdos攻撃対策について

Tags: apache, security

apacheのモジュールでdos対策をしたいと思っています。

リモートIPアドレスを元に同じIPからのアクセスの場合、 
mod_evasive等のモジュールで制限をする想定です。

ただ、ロードバランサを介したネットワーク構成の為、 
リモートIPアドレスがロードバランサのIPになってしまい、 
想定通りに制限できません。

ロードバランサからある変数でリクエストヘッダにオリジナルの 
リモートIPアドレスは設定されているので、 
（X-Forwarded-Forには設定されていません） 
そこを元に制限しようと思うのですが、 
mod_evasiveにはそのような設定や方法がありません。

他で対応できるモジュールはあるのでしょうか？

もしくはリクエストヘッダに設定されたオリジナルの 
リモートIPアドレスが制限対象となるように、 
httpdの内部のリモートIPアドレスを保持している変数に 
上書きするような方法はありますか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: DoS攻撃を律儀に負荷分散せず、ロードバランサーでブロックすべきではないでしょうか？

Comment: そもそもの話になってしまうのですが、@sayuri が仰ってるように、素直にロードバランサーでアクセスをドロップする必要があります。ロードバランサーを落とす目的で DoS 攻撃されたらひとたまりもないですよね。 仮に Amazon の Elastic Load Balancing 等を利用するなどして、直接ロードバランサーをいじれる環境でない(?)場合、それを前提として質問すると、より的確に答えを得られると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

仰るとおり、アプリケーション層での対応はそもそも無意味なものの様に思えてきました。

本件については直接ロードバランサーをいじれる環境でないです。
LBからはREMOTE_ADDRにオリジナルIPが渡されている状況で、
まずはそこを元にapacheのモジュールで何とか出来ないか模索している状態です。